# Html5 player only sound no picture

Tags: html5-video

I have a few video files with mpeg4 format, these are not playing properly in the HTML5 player. There is sound but no picture.

Link apscservices.com/kishen_test.html

The file is working in offline players like vlc and wmp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MP4 files can contain video and audio in a variety of formats with different profiles.  However what is commonly supported in an MP4 file for HTML5 video is [H.264 video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC) (also known as MPEG-4 Part 10 or MPEG-4 AVC) High Profile or lower (i.e. no more than bit depth 8, with 4:2:0 chroma subsampling), and AAC-LC or MP3 audio.  If you are using a supported audio format but an unsupported video format then you may hear sound but see no picture.

In your case you are using [MPEG-4 Part 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_2) video, which is not commonly supported by browsers, with AAC-LC audio.